# AVERAGE function not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I Have two columns containing dates.

I used this formula to find how many days there were in between the dates:

```
=DATEDIF(J7,K7,"md") &""
```

This produces the number of days without putting the word 'day/s' after it.

I have attempted to then find the average of these results using the `AVERAGE` function and it returns a value of #NUM!.

Firstly, I thought that it could be as a result of using the `DATEDIF` function. However, I have converted the values into numbers etc, yet it produces the same result.

Here is how my sheet is set out (note the values in 'Difference Between Days' aren't correct):

```
| Created Date     | Closed Date      | Difference Between Days |
|------------------|------------------|-------------------------|
| 11/08/2017 20:36 | 14/09/2017 17:45 | 33                      |
| 13/06/2017 13:36 | 25/07/2017 12:20 | 45                      |
| 12/10/2017 14:53 | 10/11/2017 23:15 | 29                      |
```

Comment: Just use `=DATEDIFF(J7,K7,"md")`. "However, I have converted the values into numbers" - NO!! You've converted number result of `DATEDIFF` to text by ` &""`.

Comment: This produces the same result.

Comment: Can you post some sample data (together with current and desired output) to help us understand your issue?

Comment: I've added it to my original question. I want to calculate the average of the numbers in 'Difference Between Days'.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with your formula with "md". I also do not encounter the error. And it also returns different result than your example. http://prntscr.com/haax8y

Comment: The results in my example aren't accurate, I just threw it together quickly as an example. The issue isn't the accuracy of the results, but the fact that AVERAGE is returning #NUM regardless of whether they are numbers or not.

Comment: how are you sure that the range you use in `average` contains only numbers? did you type them or just copy from the output of your `datediff` and paste as values?

Comment: I used numerous methods .i.e converting to text then back to numbers etc, the only thing I haven't tried is typing them in manually since there is 133 values.

Comment: I just copied out the results manually and the AVERAGE function works correctly. The original results are also numbers, yet it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Máté Juhász was correct in suggesting that the formula didn't return as a number. I created a new column and used the `VALUE` function, which has allowed the `AVERAGE` function to return the correct result.

Answer (score -1):

**@JRigress**, I would like to suggest solution for both the problems. First is about Difference of days with caption Days at the end.

Since you have not listed the date values so i'm just assuming it. For example your dates are in cell **C301 14/11/2017** & **D301 30/11/2017**, the **formula is in F301**.

= DATEDIF(C301,D301,"d")&" days" (Finding difference in Days).

other is

=DATEDIF(C301,D301,"md")&" days" (Finding difference in days ignoring Month & 
                                  Year)

**NB:** Pick the required Formula.

For first two dates you get same Result **16 Days**. But if you change the date value for example **C301 14/11/2017** & in **D301 01/01/2018** then you can find different result.

The first formula will show **48 days** and second one will show **18 days**, coz it's simply counting the difference between **14th Nov** to **1st Dec** which **is 18** (**since ignoring Month & Year**).

Now the second issue, I'm not sure what for you are using the **Average formula** but I would like to suggest you, Yes you can do it. Before apply the formula if you wish select both cells **C301** & **D301** then go to Cell Format and apply Number Format without decimal, ***remember this will not affect on previous result*** and finally use the Average formula.

=Average(C301,D301)

and you get the result **43077** (apply Number Format in the Result cell also).

I do hope I've solved both of your problems in case of any further query just post your comment.

**@JRigress,, I think when earlier I've attempted your question you have not posted the Data sheet, just now while reviewing I got so I've solved it also.**

[image]

**NB:** Both formula are same as previous only you have to change the Data Range.

Comment: My answer has got negative vote again I'm eager to learn what is wrong. It would better post your comment also help me to learn the mistake,,!!